# How to Chop parts of an expression?

Tags: plotting, complex

The following expression has four terms $T1$, $T2$, $T3$ and $T4$, such that the `totalFunction = T1 - T2 - T3 + T4;`. It turns out that the part T1-T2 gives a continuous curve. However, when T3 and T4 are also taken, we get a broken curve `totalFunction`. How can one effectively remove the terms $T3$ and $T4$, using some kind of Chop?

```
  totalFunction = T1 - T2 - T3 + T4;
T1 = 1/Log[
    2] (-1 + Sqrt[
     1 - 2 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
      2 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 - Sqrt[
       1 - 2 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
        2 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2])];
T2 = 1/Log[
    2] (1 + Sqrt[
     1 - 2 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
      2 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 + Sqrt[
       1 - 2 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
        2 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2])];
T3 = 1/(2 Log[2]) (-1 + Sqrt[
     1 - 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
      4 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 - Sqrt[
       1 - 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
        4 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2])];
T4 = 1/(2 Log[2]) (1 + Sqrt[
     1 - 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
      4 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 + Sqrt[
       1 - 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t] + 4 p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]^2 + 
        4 Abs[x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]]^2])];

Plot[{T1 - T2, T3, T4}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[{totalFunction}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Edit: Here the functions

```
p[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]=(3.27273 Abs[Sin[0.331662 t]]^2)/(
Abs[Cos[0.331662 t] - 1.50756 Sin[0.331662 t]]^2 + 
 3.27273 Abs[Sin[0.331662 t]]^2)
```

and

```
x[0, 0.4`, 0.5`, t]=((0. + 1.80907 I) (Cos[0.331662 t] - 1.50756 Sin[0.331662 t]) Sin[
  0.331662 Conjugate[t]])/(
Abs[Cos[0.331662 t] - 1.50756 Sin[0.331662 t]]^2 + 
 3.27273 Abs[Sin[0.331662 t]]^2)
```

Comment: What are the definition of `p` and `x`?

Comment: I guess you’ve already tried `Chop[totalFunction]`? What does the plot of `Chop[T3]` or `Chop[T4]` look like?

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoB. Chop[totalFunction] again gives a broken plot.

Comment: What is this `p[0, 0.4, 0.5, t]`?

Comment: p=p[0,0.4,0.5,t]

Answer (score 2):

When we remove `Abs` whenever we take the square of the term, we get something but not sure this is right.

```
p = (3.27273 
       Sin[0.331662 t]^2)/((Cos[0.331662 t] - 
        1.50756 Sin[0.331662 t])^2 + 3.27273 (Sin[0.331662 t])^2);

x = ( 1.80907 I (Cos[0.331662 t] - 1.50756 Sin[0.331662 t]) Sin[
      0.331662 Conjugate[t]])/((Cos[0.331662 t] - 
        1.50756 Sin[0.331662 t])^2 + 3.27273 Sin[0.331662 t]^2);

T1 = 1/Log[2] (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 p + p^2 + 2 x^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 p + p^2 + 2 x^2])];
T2 = 1/Log[2] (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 p + p^2 + 2 x^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 2 p + p^2 + 2 x^2])];
T3 = 1/(2 Log[2]) (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 p + 4 p^2 + 4 x^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 p + 4 p^2 + 4 x^2])];
T4 = 1/(2 Log[2]) (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 p + 4 p^2 + 4 x^2]) Log[
    1/2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 p + 4 p^2 + 4 x^2])];
totalFunction = T1 - T2 - T3 + T4;

Plot[{T1 - T2, T3, T4}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[{T1 - T2}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[totalFunction, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Okkes Dulgerci. That's exactly the curve I expect. However, x is a complex quantity so I really don't understand how it comes out so.

Comment: `x` is pure complex and you have only `x^2` term and that makes it real. `x^2 // ComplexExpand // Chop` is real

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `totalFunction` has a small imaginary part, which prevents `Plot` from doing its thing:

```
Plot[Re[totalFunction], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Im[totalFunction], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the same before. It does not work on my computer. Trust me, I'm still getting those discontinuities. Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

Comment: @TobiasFritzn If this ends up being version dependent, then including which version YOU are using in the OP would be very helpful

Comment: @MarcoB. This indeed turns out to be version dependent. Earlier I was using ver 10. I just check it with 11.3. It works fine.

Comment: @TobiasFritzn That's interesting, and rather unexpected to me. It would be worth it to self-answer your question explaining these details and mentioning the version dependence.

Comment: @MarcoB, surely. I was also thinking the same. However, right now, I am stuck with a somewhat similar kind of problem, where even 11.3 does not help me out. Could it be possible for you to help me by sharing your email? Since the question is similar to this one, I am hesitant in putting it on SE.

Comment: @Tobias Go to the chat system, you should see a "Room for MarcoB and Tobias" i just created; join that and I'll see if i can help